# Django импорт xls в базу. Импортирует в оба проекта

Tags: python, django, импорт, xls

### Задача :

скопировать сайт на django1.3, подвязать разные домены.

### Сделано :

Скопировал папку с проектом, скопировал бд, развернул отдельно виртуальное окружение, повесил на uwsgi и nginx.
все работает.

### Проблема :

В админке есть функционал - импорт прайса. Загружается xls файл и с него подтягиваются в базу цены. **Но если я загружаю прайс в domain1 , то цены обновляются и на domain2. И наоборот.**
БД подключены разные, если править товары в админке , то обновляется только на котором правил..

Код контроллера:

```
def import_1c_price(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Import1CPriceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            warehouse = form.cleaned_data['warehouse']
            row_number = form.cleaned_data['row_number']
            notification_email = form.cleaned_data['notification_email']
            notification_email = notification_email.replace(' ', '')
            notification_email = notification_email.split(',')
            data = request.FILES['price_file']
            path = default_storage.save('tmp/1c_price.{}'.format(form.cleaned_data['price_file'].name.split('.')[-1]),
                                        ContentFile(data.read()))
            tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
            from .tasks import load_1c_items_to_database
            load_1c_items_to_database.apply_async(
                args=[
                    tmp_file,
                    row_number,
                    warehouse,
                    request.user,
                    notification_email
                ],
                countdown=1,
                expires=2
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:import_1c_price'))
    else:
        form = Import1CPriceForm()
    result = {
        'title': u'Импорт прайса',
        'opts': Item._meta,
        'form': form
    }
    return render_to_response('admin/catalog/import_price.html', result, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Код функции load_1c_items_to_database:

```
def load_1c_items_to_database(tmp_file, row_number, warehouse, user, notification_email):

    exclude_list = []
    start_time = datetime.now()

    result = {
        'action': 'notification',
        'user': user.email,
        'title': u'Импорт прайса',
        'message': u'Файл загружен и уже обрабатывается.',
        'icon': '/static/images/notification_info.png'
    }

    socket_notification.apply_async(
        args=[result],
        countdown=3,
        expires=4
    )
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(tmp_file)
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    updated = 0
    article = 4
    name = 0

    if warehouse.uid == 'kiev_uid':
        count = 8
        wholesale_price = 7
        big_wholesale_price = 6
        wholesale_price_2 = 5
    else:
        count = 7
        wholesale_price = 6
        big_wholesale_price = 5
        wholesale_price_2 = None
    errors = ''
    not_found_items = []
    for rownum in range(row_number, sheet.nrows):
        try:
            row = sheet.row_values(rownum)
            if len(row) < 8:
                continue
            try:
                article_val = u'%s' % decimal.Decimal(row[article])
            except:
                article_val = u'%s' % row[article]

            if article_val and row[name]:
                item = Item.objects.filter(article=article_val, warehouse=warehouse)

                if item:
                    item = item[0]
                    item.count = row[count]
                    item.wholesale_price = row[wholesale_price] if row[wholesale_price] else 0
                    item.big_wholesale_price = row[big_wholesale_price] if row[big_wholesale_price] else 0
                    if wholesale_price_2:
                        item.wholesale_price_2 = row[wholesale_price_2] if row[wholesale_price_2] else 0
                    try:
                        item.name = row[name].strip()[:128]
                    except Exception as e:
                        item.name = str(row[name])
                    item.save()
                    updated += 1
                    exclude_list.append(item.id)
                else:
                    not_found_items.append([article_val, row[name]])
        except Exception, e:
            continue

    Item.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse).exclude(id__in=exclude_list).update(
        wholesale_price=0,
        wholesale_price_2=0,
        wholesale_price_3=0,
        wholesale_price_4=0,
        big_wholesale_price=0
    )
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'tmp'))

    updated_text = u''
    if updated:
        updated_text = u'\nТоваров обновлено {}шт.'.format(updated)
    messages_text = u"Импорт данных успешно завершен!{}".format(updated_text)
    result = {
        'action': 'notification',
        'user': user.email,
        'title': u'Импорт прайса',
        'message': messages_text,
        'icon': '/static/images/notification_success.png'
    }

    socket_notification.apply_async(
        args=[result],
        countdown=3,
        expires=4
    )

    end_time = datetime.now()
    service_mail = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    from_email = u'%s <%s>' % ('MobiMag', service_mail, )
    txt_content = render_to_string('catalog/emails_admin/import_results.txt', {
        'messages_text': messages_text,
        'not_found_items': not_found_items,
        'warehouse': warehouse,
        'end_time': end_time,
        'start_time': start_time
    })
    html_content = render_to_string('catalog/emails_admin/import_results.html', {
        'messages_text': messages_text,
        'not_found_items': not_found_items,
        'warehouse': warehouse,
        'end_time': end_time,
        'start_time': start_time
    })
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=u'Результаты импорта для склада {}'.format(warehouse.name),
        body=txt_content,
        from_email=from_email,
        to=notification_email
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')

    msg.send(fail_silently=True)
    return
```

Comment: 1.3? Вам бы об обновлении задуматься пора.

Comment: @m9_psy такой задачи пока не стоит). Та и половины зависимостей уже нету в репозиториях.